# Rooting a phone that doesn't have stock rom download on the internet

Tags: rooting, stock-rom

I've posted here [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/238824/tried-to-ungoogle-my-android-device-but-accidentally-removed-a-vital-package-a) earlier about me needing help to restore a system application that I uninstalled using adb. After trying for the entire day with no solution I've decided to download Bromite as webview, however since I have an unrooted android 5.1, I can't change the default webviewer to Bromite (I had uninstalled the google webviewer). I've got two choices left now, which is rooting my phone and hard resetting, and I would rather risk it rooting my phone since I got a ton of important 2fa on it.

As reference, my android version is 5.1

My phone model is Coolpad porto S E570,  in numbers - CP8722_U00

I've looked up a couple of guides on how to root the device but most of the legit rooting methods require having a stock ROM of your device that is going to patched, and later, installed. However, after searching the web for a while I just can't seem to find any stock ROMs that are for CP8722_U00, only for CP8722_S00 which I assume is probably incompatible.

The less legit looking guides said to use tools like Kingoroot, however the public reception on them is mixed to say the least, some outright saying that it's malware.

So my question is this: Are there any other ways to root, maybe obtain stock ROM for my device without root? Or do I have to sell my soul to those one click root applications?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The default webview component can be set in the Android Settings Developer Options menu. For accessing this you don't need root.

Comment: Worst case, there's a guide to [manually root an Android device](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/217116/44325)

Comment: There is no option to replace the default webview component in android 5.1. AFAIK that feature got added in Android 7.0+. And I'll definitely try out the manual root method, Andrew.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Smart Phone flash tool - Readback - EMMC_USER backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220584/smart-phone-flash-tool-readback-emmc-user-backup)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Backup/dump kernel image (and full ROM) without root for Mediatek Devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203283/backup-dump-kernel-image-and-full-rom-without-root-for-mediatek-devices)

Comment: Yeah, this actually was the solution I ended up going with, thanks. I'm still a bit worried because my processor isn't supported by the sp flash tool, but fingers crossed.